# Improve SQL Server insert query performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a main table with millions of records with huge amounts of data. I regularly insert 300 records into the main table from temp table.

Every time I clear the temp table and insert newly created 300 records into the temp table. Sometimes the insert query is taking more than 10 seconds to insert into main table. How can we improve this performance?

```
INSERT INTO MAINTABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3)
    SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 
    FROM #TEMP
```

Comment: try creating indexes in your main table and see the performance. Also, try inserting data in batches so that it does not fill up your transaction log.

Comment: No way we can answer without more information about your database. I suggest posting an execution plan.

Comment: @Avi I'm not sure how indexes would help increase write performance. If anything it should decrease the performance due to overhead of updating the indexes

Comment: Without understanding the usage patterns of the tables it's worth noting that reducing the indexes on the MAINTABLE table will reduce the performance overhead on the RDBMS to update the indexes.  Also, ensure that the TEMP table is in memory.  Also, remove any unnecessary records and columns in the TEMP table to reduce the number of rows read.

Comment: You must give us more information ..for example how you generate this #Temp ? ....is a procedure or just this query ? ...I mean ..this query is OK.

Comment: there might be the chance that actually creating your temp table will take time in creating records, please share your sample code for creating this temp table. Also query execution plan is much helpful in understanding this problem in more details.

Comment: This is too broad.  The issue could be due to many factors, such as indexes on the main table, triggers, clustered indexes, load on the server, locking on the temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

Temp tables are Created in **Tempdb Database**, they create additional overhead for SQL Server, slowing overall performance.

One Another Option is that.....if You are using Temp Table ...then..try to avoid transaction....sometime it's make your query performance slow(Depending on your Data Capcity..).

Instead you can use Table variables...Table variables are accessible only within the session that created them.

Note:-- There is no Limit for define the size of table variables because it Depends on Memory Size..

[Maximum Capicity of Table Variable](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/aeb2799a-6458-401c-899d-4cb01af90f1d/maximum-capicity-of-table-variable)